# Deducing the types

Tags: c++, c++11, effective-c++

I am trying to understand type deduction while walking through Scott Meyer's Effective Modern C++.

Consider the code snippet below:

```
template<typename T>
void f(const T& param); // param is now a ref-to-const; paramType is const T&

int x = 27; // as before
const int cx = x; // as before
const int& rx = x; // as before

f(x); // T is int, param's type is const int&
f(cx); // T is int, param's type is const int&
f(rx); // T is int, param's type is const int&
```

He says that since the `paramType` is a reference, we can follow a two step procedure to deduce the type of `T`:

1. Ignore references (if any) in `expr` (i.e., `x`, `cx` and `rx`)
2. Pattern match the type of `expr` and `paramType`

Now when `cx` is a `const int`:

> cx -> const int
>
> paramType -> reference to const int

So, according to the logic mentioned, shouldn't `T` be a `const int` due to pattern matching (and not just `int`)?  I understand that the `const`ness of `cx` has been passed over to `paramType`, but is what he says, wrong?  Is this 2 step procedure that he has mentioned not to be followed as a rule of thumb?  How do you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You are misrepresenting something. What is `paramType`?

Comment: @KerrekSB, it is `const T&`.  I have included that in the comments (in the 2nd line of the code).

Comment: Don't use comments. Refer only to things in the actual code. I have no idea what the comment means. Say "the type of `param`" instead.

Comment: It's easier to wrap your head around if you interpret `const T&` as "`const` reference to `T`" instead of "reference to `const T`"; a `const` entity can only bind to a `const` reference, but non-cv entities can bind to both `const` and non-`const` references.

Comment: In most cases these are effectively identical (a `const` reference to `int` effectively views the `int` as `const`, regardless of whether it is or not), but not always (for example, [when working with references to pointers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dec25cd9282f349); `const int*&` is a non-cv reference to `const int*`, but `int* const&` is a `const` reference to `int*`, which is identical to the syntax difference between a pointer to `const int` (`const int*`) and a `const` pointer to `int` (`int* const`)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [his book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do) Scott uses this "notation":

```
template<typename T>
void f(ParamType param); // where `ParamType` depends on T
```

So let's do pattern matching for `ParamType` when `param` is `const int`. We have:

```
const T & <----> const int // <----> is symbolic notation for pattern matching
```

So `T` is deduced as `int`, hence `ParamType` is `const int&`.

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I was looking for.  One question though - you mention in the comments, `where ParamType depends on T` - isn't it the other way round?

Comment: @user6490375 No, `ParamType` is a type function of `T`, like `const T*`.

Comment: I had misunderstood pattern matching to be something like a set intersection.  (Maybe because I understood everything that matches to be a part of the pattern).  So I deduced T to be `const int`.

Answer (score 1):

When `cx` is `const int`, then `T` is deduced as `int` so that `const T& param` is `const int& param`, i.e. `param` is of type `const int&`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am however looking for the answer in view of the two steps mentioned in the book.  I believe understanding these two steps would be helpful to deduce complex types.